# Assigning of value in fast report variable

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport

Hi I'm new in Delphi and I'm dealing with creating a reports for newly hired employee. I'm using Fast Report, Delphi XE2 and Firebird database.

I have a problem in writing a condition for the value of my variables. 
I want the value of my variable to be handled value such as 'HIGH SCHOOL GRADUATE if the EDU_COLL_REMARK field value is null. and `COLLEGE GRADUATE` if it has a value.. just Like I did.

```
if dmapp.sqtrans.parambyname('EDU_COLL_REMARK').IsNull then
        dmapp.frxReport1.Variables['edu'] := QuotedStr('HIGH SCHOOL GRADUATE');
else
   dmapp.frxReport1.Variables['edu'] := QuotedStr('COLLEGE GRADUATE');
```

but it doesnt work. It returns an

> Error SQTrans: Parameter EDU_COLL_REMARK not found.

Whats wrong? please help me.

this is my whole codes:

```
dmApp.sqTRANS.SQL.Clear;
   dmApp.sqtrans.SQL.Add('Select s.SKILLS_NAME, c.CUST_NAME, e.FULL_NAME, e.REFER_1NAME, e.HIRE_DATE, e.AGE, e.HEIGHT_FEET, e.HEIGHT_INCH, e.EDU_COLL_REMARK, e.TEST_1TITLE, e.SEC_EXPERIENCE_YEARS, e.CELL_NO, e.ADDRESS_LINE FROM EMPLOYEE e INNER JOIN CUSTOMER c ' +
                        'on e.CUST_NO=c.CUST_NO ' +
                        'FULL JOIN SKILLSTABLE s on e.SKILLS_NO=s.SKILLS_NO ' +
                        'WHERE EXTRACT(MONTH FROM HIRE_DATE) = :M_HIRE_DATE ' +
                        'AND EXTRACT(YEAR FROM HIRE_DATE) = :Y_HIRE_DATE ' +
                        'order by HIRE_DATE DESC');
    dmApp.sqTRANS.ParamByName('M_HIRE_DATE').AsString := FormatDateTime('MM', dpdate.Date);
    dmApp.sqTRANS.ParamByName('Y_HIRE_DATE').AsString := FormatDateTime('yyyy', dpdate.Date);
     if dmapp.sqtrans.parambyname('EDU_COLL_REMARK').IsNull then
        dmapp.frxReport1.Variables['edu'] := QuotedStr('HIGH SCHOOL GRADUATE');
else
dmapp.frxReport1.Variables['edu'] := QuotedStr('COLLEGE GRADUATE');
    dmApp.sqTRANS.ExecSQL();

    dmApp.frxDBDataset1.DataSet := dmApp.sqTRANS;
    dmApp.frxReport1.LoadFromFile('c:\vitech3\NewlyHired.fr3');
    dmapp.frxReport1.variables['COMPANYNAME'] := QuotedStr(Globals.GetCompanyName);
    dmapp.frxReport1.variables['COMPANYADD'] := QuotedStr(Globals.GetCompanyAddr + ' Cubao, Quezon City');
    dmapp.frxReport1.variables['CAPTION'] := QuotedStr('Newly Hired Report for ' + FormatDateTime('MMMM', dpdate.date) + ' ' + FormatDateTime('yyyy', dpdate.date));

    dmApp.frxReport1.ShowReport();
```

Answer (score 1):

`EDU_COLL_MARK` is not a 'parameter' of your query; the parameters are those items prefixed with a ':'.

Return the value you want from the query, though.  Have a look at `case .. when` in the Firebird docs.  This will show you how to return a conditional value from your query.

```
SELECT
 CASE EDU_COLL_MARK
   WHEN NULL THEN 'HIGH SCHOOL GRADUATE'
   ELSE 'COLLEGE GRADUATE'
 END AS EDU
FROM ...
```

-------------- or perhaps

```
SELECT
 CASE COALESCE(EDU_COLL_MARK, '')
   WHEN '' THEN 'HIGH SCHOOL GRADUATE'
   ELSE 'COLLEGE GRADUATE'
 END AS EDU
FROM ...
```

Comment: Thank you Sir, But I got new error it says: Dbexpress driver does not support the TDBXtypes.UNKNOWN data type. Vendor Error Message. Unknown ISC Error 0. What does it mean?

Comment: Oh! you've change your answer. I'll try again.

Comment: Hi Sir, I run your code and it shows college graduate only. even the other employee which is null, still return the same value.

Comment: Without some sample data I cannot easily help you any further

Comment: Just to maybe make it easier to see what is going on, you could try returning the variable EDU_COLL_MARK and then return the result of the CASE statement.  That might show you what you are getting so you could maybe figure out the problem.

Comment: EDU_COLL_REMARK is my field for those employee who took college. example data is 'Graduate'. If its null then it means that their educational attainment is either Primary or Secondary only. Now, I want my report to display their educational attainment if its Graduate in college or not. Does my idea was okay or I'm just make it complicated?

Comment: This is not too complicated, it is a standard problem.  I have no Firebird instance to play with so I have not run the query myself, but I am guessing that you are mistaken that there are NULLs in the data.  See my edit.